# How delete an ipad app totally (rather than it continuing to exist when viewed over in iTunes)?

Tags: ipad, applications

On my iPad, there are many apps that I owned once, didn't enjoy much, and then deleted.

However, if I go to iTunes and then open up the section pertaining to my iPad, I still see these many old apps listed (just that their check-boxes are unchecked, symbolizing that they are not copied over onto the iPad.)

I would like to totally delete these from the iTunes world too. Partially because I did a sync today which caused them to awake from the dead and get re-synced to my computer... and partly just out of a sense of completeness and health.

NOTES: I have tried to click one of the unwelcome apps and then go to the Edit menu and choose Delete.  But Delete is greyed out! even though that app's checkbox is unchecked. ALSO, note, I have my iPad synced to the computer via WiFi -- I can't imagine that causes the problem?

What is the official, graceful, good way to fully delete these apps so they don't exist, even in ghost form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iTunes in the left hand sidebar go to Apps into the Library selection. If you delete the app there it will not show up in the sync section. In case you need it again you can always download it from the Store again (as long as it is available there).

[image]

Comment: Heh -- thank you very much.  Perhaps it was dumb of me, but I'm sure glad for the info -- eric